# SUM FIRST_VALUE or SUM group by while still showing all rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a table like below:

```
InvoiceNum, CreditNum, ItemID,  TotalCreditDetail, TotalCredit, TotalCost, SumCreditDetailTaxed
001       , 001      , ITEM-A,  340              , 20811      , 20894.84 , 340
001       , 002      , ITEM-B,  0                , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-C,  4510             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-D,  1424             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-E,  2230             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-F,  5225             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-G,  3400             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-H,  1242             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-I,  2200             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
001       , 002      , ITEM-J,   240             , 20811      , 20894.84 , 20471
```

I am trying to get a column with "uncategorizedcredit", basically credit not associated with an ItemID. TotalCredit is unique to the InvoiceNum, so would I get this number by subtracting `FIRST_VALUE(TotalCredit) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNum) - SUM(TotalCreditDetail) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNum) as UncategorizedCredit`? I think I may have answered my own question on how to calculate UncategorizedCredit, but I'm not sure. I just found `FIRST_VALUE` today. I'm currently using a `SUM(CASE WHEN... )` to calculate it, but it's messy and seems to require me to `SUM()` with a group by and then un-group by to get all the details I need for the report.

Afterwards, I would need to SUM the UncategorizedCredit Column for a total for the whole report in CrystalReports. This is where it gets a bit tricky, as the report is grouped by ITEM and InvoiceNum 002 may have ITEM-C and ITEM-D, InvoiceNum 003 may have ITEM-H and ITEM-I, etc.. Right now I am using variables to add the numbers from the details of the report to a total. I would like to then go back and subtract any uncategorizedcredit from the grand total.

My question is, how do I add this per-invoice value with the report grouped by ITEM-ID? I considered using an array to store the InvoiceNum of what I had already summed, but arrays max out at 1000 and there will be well over that number in this report.

I guess I could use `SUM(UncategorizedCredit) OVER() as TotalUncategorizedCredit` in a new select statement that is selected from the previous select statement?

I can't use nested selects because CrystalReports applies a filter / where clause to the data and the totals wouldn't be accurate. To get the TotalCreditDetail and SumCreditDetailTaxed I'm currently using ~8-10 JOINS of various types, some `RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table) ON x = y`. I don't actually have the SQL in front of me, and will try the SUMs tomorrow, but if `FIRST_VALUE` doesn't work then I'm not sure what else to do.

This will probably only amount to a thousand dollars difference, but I'm trying to account for everything.

Comment: Please show your expected results, and your closest query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select invoicenum,
       (TotalCredit - sum(TotalCreditDetail)) as uncategorizedCredit
from t
group by invoicenum, TotalCredit;
```

`first_value()` is not actually needed for this -- because the values are the same on every row.  So as window functions, this could be done as:

```
select t.*,
       (max(TotalCredit) over (partition by invoicenum) -
        sum(TotalCreditDetail) over (partition by invoicenum)
       ) as uncategorizedCredit
from t;
```

You could use `first_value()` instead of `min()`/`max()` -- but the latter is simpler to type.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon,

Thank you for your response. I'm not able to use group by because I need every row ungrouped to show the individual items in the report. However, reminding me that FIRST_VALUE was the same as MIN/MAX (doh) helped significantly with my searches.

I managed to solve it, if your curious, here is the SQL query that I ended up with:

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ReportB.RowNum = 1 THEN UncategorizedCredit ELSE 0 END) OVER () as TotalUncategorizedCredit,
    *
FROM (
        SELECT 
            FIRST_VALUE(TotalCredit) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNum ORDER BY InvoiceNum) - SUM(TotalCreditDetail) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNum Order BY InvoiceNum) as UncategorizedCredit,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by InvoiceNum ORDER BY InvoiceNum) as RowNum,
            InvoiceNum,
            CreditNum,
            TotalCreditDetail,
            TotalCredit,
            TotalCost,
            SumCreditDetailTaxed
        FROM (SELECT *  FROM [table]) as Report
) ReportB
```

I needed to add a ROW_NUMBER() column partitioned by the same and then filter the SUM using CASE WHEN so that it only added it when the row number was 1.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Jared